# Excel VBA: Creating "fall through" in nested if-else statements, and also allowing normal behaviour?

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel VBA macro, I wanted to try and create "fall through" in some nested if-else statements. But I also wanted then to function as normal if-else statements as well.

My solution below seems to work. Is there anything wrong with this method?

I know using `Goto` is frowned upon, but it's the only way I could think of solving the problem.

```
    If fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr1

If fallThrough = False and criteria = crit1 Then
Cr1:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 1"        

ElseIf fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr2

ElseIf fallThrough = False And criteria = crit2 Then
Cr2:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 2"    
    If fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr3

ElseIf fallThrough = False And criteria = crit3 Then
Cr3:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 3"
    If fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr4

ElseIf fallThrough = False And criteria = crit4 Then
Cr4:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 4"

End If
```

Comment: That looks like it would be very difficult to maintain or even follow. Is there some specific problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @TimWilliams Just trying to reduce code and make things efficient, so I'm not repeating myself. It just so happens I needed one subroutine to fall through these if-elses, and another to treat them as normal, so I did this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make what you want to do separate subs and call them within a normal if.

```
Sub main(fallThrough As Boolean)
If fallThrough Then
    critsub1
    critsub2
    critsub3
    critsub4
Else
    If criteria = crit1 Then
        critsub1
    ElseIf criteria = crit2 Then
        critsub2
    ElseIf criteria = crit3 Then
        critsub3
    ElseIf criteria = crit4 Then
        critsub4
    End If
End If
End Sub

Sub critsub1()
MsgBox "Criteria 1"
End Sub

Sub critsub2()
MsgBox "Criteria 2"
End Sub

Sub critsub3()
MsgBox "Criteria 3"
End Sub

Sub critsub()
MsgBox "Criteria 4"
End Sub
```

Yes you repeat the calls in the if but this is easier to read and maintain.

Another method is to create individual Ifs:

```
If (Not fallThrough And criteria = crit1) Or fallThrough Then critsub1
If (Not fallThrough And criteria = crit2) Or fallThrough Then critsub2
If (Not fallThrough And criteria = crit3) Or fallThrough Then critsub3
If (Not fallThrough And criteria = crit4) Or fallThrough Then critsub4
```

This way there is not repeating at all

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend avoiding `GoTo` unless absolutely necessary, and if you find yourself in a situation where `GoTo` is *necessary* then find someone who is much more experienced than you are and they'll show you why it isnt.

There are a few problems with `GoTo`. First, it allows us to create lazier and more inefficient processes to solve a task. Keep in mind that pretty much any task can be handled with the right combination of logic, its just a matter of training our ability to write that logic. **Programming is 99% logic, 1% code.** This may be a bit of a reductionist way of thinking about programming, but most early coding problems can be solved in infinitely many inefficient ways and still work, but our task is to solve problems the *right* way.

Second, `GoTo` makes it difficult to *see* what your code is *really* doing.

So, how do we solve this problem without `GoTo`? We use **Abstraction**.

```
Public Funtion CriteriaMatches(ByVal ControlCriteria as String, ByVal TestCriteria as String) as Boolean
    CriteriaMatches = (ControlCriteria  = TestCriteria )
End Function
```

Then, we implement our function to reduce the first layer of redundancy:

```
If fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr1

If fallThrough = False and CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit1) Then
Cr1:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 1"        

ElseIf fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr2

ElseIf fallThrough = False And CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit2) Then
Cr2:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 2"    
    If fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr3

ElseIf fallThrough = False And CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit3) Then
Cr3:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 3"
    If fallThrough = True Then GoTo Cr4

ElseIf fallThrough = False And CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit4) Then
Cr4:
    'MsgBox "Criteria 4"

End If
```

This doesnt do much beyond wrapping a comparison in a function call, but the main benefit here is that if `ControlCriteria = TestCriteria` becomes `ControlCriteria <> TestCriteria` then we can make this change in *one* place.

Next, we need some way of allowing the function to return `False` if our `FallThrough` = `True`. The reason we want to return a `False` value is because we want to skip the action if `FallThrough` is true. This is simple enough to do:

```
Public Funtion CriteriaMatches(ByVal ControlCriteria as String, ByVal TestCriteria as String, Optional byVal ReturnFalse as Boolean = False) as Boolean
    If ReturnFalse Then CriteriaMatches = (ControlCriteria  = TestCriteria )
End Function
```

Since the implicit value return of a `Boolean` function is `False` we dont need to add an `If/Else` block.

Now our code becomes:

```
If CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit1, PassThrough) Then
    'MsgBox "Criteria 1"        
ElseIf CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit1, PassThrough) Then
    'MsgBox "Criteria 2"    
ElseIf CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit2, PassThrough) Then
    'MsgBox "Criteria 3"
ElseIf CriteriaMatches(criteria, crit3, PassThrough) Then
    'MsgBox "Criteria 4"
End If
```

The code is much neater, easier to read, and still performs in the same way (with the exception of repeating the `msgbox` command which would have happened with the placement of the labels.

I am certain that this code could be reduced even further (such as passing in a list of arguments to compare to, and returning the position of the matched argument) but for now this will do.

The key here is to learn new code patterns that help you solve problems that you couldn't solve before. VBA has patterns and anti-patterns for a good reason, and it is important to seek to avoid them as much as humanly possible.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply. Very helpful.

Comment: This will not produce all four outcomes when `PassThrough` is TRUE.  Once the IF finds the first true it will not test the others.  When `PassThrough` it will only do the first and not the other three.  You will need to change the `ElseIF` to individual `If` so it check all four

Comment: If I am reading his code correctly, `FallThrough` causes the code to literally fall through, and skip all of the conditions. The use of If/ElseIf here was intentional for that purpose. I did note that I intentionally didnt have it repeat commands (`msgbox "Message One"` etc.), but this could be easily added, or as you note, this could be converted to a block of `If's` but before doing so I would be very wary of any need to create such a construct since really the entire block should be wrapped in an `If PassThrough Then` since passthrough would be unchanging, and only the conditions to check.

Comment: To clarify, I would only recommend wrapping it in the first check if he did want a block of `If`'s vs, the `ElseIf`. I did update the function to make `PassThrough` optional to allow for this style though.

Answer (score 0):

### Setting a flag

Setting a flag is a very simple and maintainable way to create a fall through:

```
Dim Break As Boolean

If Not Break And Condition1 Then
    'Do Something
End If

If Not Break And Condition2 Then
    'Do Something
End If

If Not Break And Condition3 Then
    'Do Something
    Break = True 'Stop doing anything else
End If


If Not Break And Condition4 Then
    'Do Something
    Break = True 'Stop doing anything else
End If
```

### For Loop with Select case

Although a little farcical, I think this pattern best emulates the Select statements of other languages.

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Select Case i
    Case 1
        'Do Something
    Case 2
        'Do Something
    Case 3
        'Do Something
        Exit For ' Break Code
    Case 4
        Exit For ' Break Code
    Case Else

    End Select
Next i
```